# How can I make a text colorful when I click in vsCode editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I'm using vsCode on windows. When I click "ffa" in the editor, the all of "ffa" text come to be colorful. But when I click reserved word "for", it wouldn't. When I click "function" as well. I would make to be colorful even if it is a reserved word, whatever. My color theme for vsCode is Palenight theme. And I'm using Julia language.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setting is controlled by `"editor.occurrencesHighlight"` in VSCode's setting, and unfortunately it does not highlight keywords (only symbols).

As an alternative, you can double click the `if` keyword, and if `"editor.selectionHighlight"` is set to `True`, VSCode will highlight all occurrences of the highlighted word (which can be a keyword, like `if` or `for`)